# Conditional inclusion of JARs in a WAR built by Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have to build a war file using maven to include jars conditionally,
each jar is created by a seperate maven project which deploys  jar to nexus(our organisations remote) repository

Eg : I have jars like these core.jar,reward.jar,payment.jar,domains.jar so on
I need to build a final war based on conditions(environmnet) to include above jars

Combination of final war(w1)
w1.war : core.jar,domains.jar
w1.war : core.jar,domains.jar,rewards.jar(Any way to specify to include this jar if rewards is applicable)

Comment: Hey Aniketh, welcome to stackoverflow. What is your question and what is your approach to find a solution? Here you can get more info on Asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why is is needed to build the same project using different dependencies? This means in consequence it is a different project. Which means from my point of view you should create separate projects(war's) which represent that...

Comment: @khmarbaise : If seperate wars are created then context to access the web resources is also changed which will effect the existing clients, in our case the context should be same----features will be added as per requirement eg: w1.war with rewards feature, w1.war with out reward

Answer (score 4):

The [Maven WAR Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/plugin-info.html) allows you to include/exclude JARs. For example:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <packagingExcludes>
        WEB-INF/lib/excluded.jar
      </packagingExcludes>
      <packagingIncludes>
        WEB-INF/lib/included.jar
      </packagingIncludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

You can associate the inclusions/exclusions with a condition by using profiles. For example, let the WAR plugin use properties (${excludedResources}, ${includedResources}) ...

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <packagingExcludes>
        ${excludedResources}
      </packagingExcludes>
      <packagingIncludes>
        ${includedResources}
      </packagingIncludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

... and define values for those properties via profiles:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>prod</id>
      <properties>
        <excludedResources>WEB-INF/lib/a.jar,WEB-INF/lib/b.jar</excludedResources>
        <includedResources>WEB-INF/lib/c.jar</includedResources>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>tst</id>
      <properties>
        <excludedResources>WEB-INF/lib/x.jar,WEB-INF/lib/y.jar</excludedResources>
        <includedResources>WEB-INF/lib/z.jar</includedResources>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

So, you can use the Maven WAR Plugin's built-in ability to tweak the WAR contents and you can make these tweaks conditional by using Maven profiles.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `profiles` capabilities in maven. Each dependency can be included into its own profile block e.g. `domains` will be included only if you switch this profile on and services - by `services` profile.
At the same time you can identify common jars through the common dependency block (in our case `core.jar` will be common)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>conditional-war</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>War Which Includes Jar By Conditions</name>

    <!-- Common dependency block which will be always included -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <!-- Profile for domains jars. Will be included by
             profile\condition "domains" -->
        <profile>
            <id>domains</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>domains</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
                    <artifactId>domains</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <!-- Profile for domains jars. Will be included by
             profile\condition "services" -->
        <profile>
            <id>services</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>services</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
                    <artifactId>services</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Command line for the activation can be following:

1. By this command line will be included core.jar and domains.jar

   `mvn clean install -Pdomains`
2. In such case war will include core.jar and services.jar

   `mvn clean install -Pservices`
3. And finally by this command line will be included all the jars

   `mvn clean install -Pdomains,services`